# If $ f(z) = \exp(z^2)$ , calculate $f^{(20)}(0)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am reading introductory to complex analysis in an engineering class.

Solution 1:

We could manually calculate the first 20 terms for the maclaurin series $ f(z) = \exp(z^2) $ by using the definition of the maclaurin series. This would take forever though.

Beginning of solution 2:

We know that $C_{20} =  \frac{f^{(20)}(0)}{20!}$ which implies that  $f^{(20)}(0) = C_{20} \cdot 20!$.

If we calculate $C_{20}$ we have solved the problem.

Since $f(z)$ analytical everywhere (I think?) there exists a maclaurin series with an infinite radius of convergence with the coefficients: 
\begin{equation}C_{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_p} \frac{f(s)}{s^{n+1}} ds
\end{equation}

where $C_p$ is the closed circle $|s| = p $ inside the radius of convergence for $f$.

For $n=20$ we have

\begin{equation}C_{20} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_p} \frac{f(s)}{s^{21}} ds
\end{equation}

and with $f(s) = \exp(s^2)$ we get

\begin{equation}C_{20} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_p} \frac{\exp(s^2)}{s^{21}} ds.
\end{equation}

Since $C_p$ is a circle we could parametrize it but I think that would make the integral very messy, so I have not attempted that yet. Any help appreciated.

Before posting solutions please note that this problem is based on an introductory course for *engineers*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}z^n
$$
we have
$$
e^{z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}z^{2n}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k
$$
Comparing coefficients, which is possible because the Taylor (or MacLaurin, if you prefer) series is unique, we get
$$
\frac{f^{(20)}(0)}{20!}=\frac{1}{10!}
$$

Comment: This is an accepted answer. Would it be possible to calculate the coefficient by calculating the integral in my solution?

Comment: @Gustaf It's surely possible, but I don't think I'd attempt it. `;-)`